# Windows Explorer Context Menu Integration, get file that was right clicked on

Tags: windows, contextmenu, registry, right-click

I've already figured out how to add a menu item to the right click context menu of the windows explorer using the registry. I currently have it set to launch my application when my menu item is clicked.

However, I want to know if there is a way to know what file is was right clicked on. I thought it would have been sent as a command line argument to the launched program, but it's not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `%L` in the command line for the application you are launching at the place where you want the file name.

Comment: This doesn't really do that, it fails if you right click `*.lnk` file, `%L` gives target file, I'm looking for a way to get the clicked file, no matter if it is a link or not.